# What is the simplest multilinear function in two variables?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

The basic initial property such a function must have is:
 f(x,0)=0 for any x
and 
 f(0,y)=0 
for any y.

But does a multilinear f(x,y) have a general form, In the same way a linear f(x,y) has a general form A*x+B*y where A and B are real constants.

thanks!

Comment: Then $A=B=0$..?

Comment: Welcome to Math SX! $Axy$ is the simplest bilinear function of two variables.

Comment: of course ! Thanks!